# Access base class fn with same signature from derived class object

Tags: c++, derived-class, base-class

Is it possible to access a base class function which has the same signature as that of a derived class function using a derived class object?. here's a sample of what I'm stating below..

```
class base1 {
public:
    void test()
    {cout<<"base1"<<endl;};
};

class der1 : public base1 {
public:
    void test()
    {cout<<"der1"<<endl;};
};

int main() {
der1 obj;
obj.test(); // How can I access the base class 'test()' here??
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe 'override' tag should be removed. I am not 100% sure, but I believe the correct term is 'hide' rather than override.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the method name as it conflicts with the inherited one.

Use obj.base1::test()

Comment: The formal term is "overrides", since the signatures match. Otherwise you'd say the derived "hides" the base class method. In either case, there is no "inherited method name" anymore.

Comment: I doubt whether the correct term is 'override' or 'hides'. In the C++ standard 'override' is only used with virtual functions and in 10.2 Member name lookup, the standard says: 'A member name f in one sub-object B hides a member name f in a sub-object A if A is a base class sub-object of B.'

Comment: @MSalters:  This is definitely not "overriding".  That is only for virtual functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override a method in derived class if you didn't provide a virtual key word.

```
class base1
{
    public:
        void test()
        {
            cout << "base1" << endl;
        };
};

class der1 : public base1
{
    public:
        void test()
        {
            cout << "der1" << endl;
        };
};

int main()
{
    der1 obj;
    obj.test(); // How can I access the base class 'test()' here??
    return 0;
}
```

So the above code is wrong. You have to give:

```
virtual void test();
```

in your base class

Comment: @Styne666 Please do not be rude in your "edit summary".  That's visible to everyone.  Read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette) - "*Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated*"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
((base)obj).test();
```